# Refresh related products of a configurable product - Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, related-products

I am searching for a solution to change related products if the customer choose another attribute / simple product of this configurable product.

For example I have a configurable product with the attribute color red and black. Both simple products (red and black) got different related products.

If I enter the configurable product and change the color, I will only see the related product that is connected with the main configurable product. The related products will not refresh depending on my choice.

Do you have a solution for this?

thank you very much.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? We need to do the same